# How to debug "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'func' of undefined" in React?

Tags: reactjs

## Already done

1. npm install -save prop-types
2. import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
3. npm install --save react-router
4. import {Router, Route, Link} from 'react-router';

I have done everything but I can not do it.

## ContactCreate.class

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router';

/*skip*/

ContactCreate.propTypes ={
    onCreate : React.PropTypes.func
};
```

## package.json

[image]

I tried everything that other people have put into the solution but the result was the same. There seems to be no problem with the code, but I do not know what the problem is.

## Contact.js

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    /*skip*/
    this, handleCreate = this.handleCreate.bind(this);
}

handleCreate(contact) {
    this.setState({
        contactData: update(this.state.contactData, { $push: [contact] })
    });
}

/*skip*/

render() {
/*skip*/
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Contacts</h1>
            <input
                name="keyword"
                placeholder="Search"
                value={this.state.keyword}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
            <div>{mapToComponents(this.state.contactData)}</div>
            <ContactDetails
                isSelected={this.state.selectedKey != -1}
                contact={this.state.contactData[this.state.selectedKey]}
            />
            <ContactCreate
                onCreate={this.handleCreate}
            />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PropTypes` is imported from a separate package and hence shouldn't be used like `React.PropTypes.func`, but `PropTypes.func`

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router';

...

ContactCreate.propTypes ={
    onCreate : PropTypes.func
};
```

Comment: The following error occurs 
==>> ReferenceError: handleCreate is not defined

Comment: is handleCreate defined in some part of your code, where exactly is this error pointing

Comment: Please confirm that you just posted.

Comment: You have a typo here `this, handleCreate = this.handleCreate.bind(this);` also can you point out where exactly is the error pointing